# In SharePoint 2013 is redirected page still accessible to edit for global nav, etc

Tags: 2013, redirect

If I use a redirect from my parent site to a subsite, can I still get into the parent site to work on the navigation?    If yes, how?

I'm concerned about an endless loop, and it's imperative I can still edit the parent.  (My subsite will become my "homepage" allowing me to retain all the files within the parent.)

"This is the code: Edit the home page of the root site and add Script Editor webpart to the page and paste the following code into it.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0"; url=http://www.subsitepagelocation">
```

This will redirect users to the new page immediately."

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Users will only be redirected from the page where the Script Editor is. All the other pages will still be accessible and won't do any redirect.

So if you add a SEWP with a redirect to home.aspx, default.aspx will not redirect etc.

Just add `/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` to the parent site URL to access the navigation for the top site.

To make any page redirect in the parent site, i think you need to create a redirect rule in IIS using IIS rewrite module.

[URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)